# Free hierarchical DataGridView with DataBinding support

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm searching for a DataGridView derrived class that show data in hierarchical way and supports DataBinding like regular DataGridView does. Do you any of this? Free?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've searched for something similar but this is what I've found.  It will do a parent to child relationship as needed.

http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/HierarGrid.aspx

No Trial or serial just the control and you can download the source.  It's customizable and has a good tutorial page on how to use it.

Comment: thank you, it seems like a good solution, but for web development. And i need something like this for desktop